# How to load LinkedHashMap Values into Hashtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, hashtable, linkedhashmap

I have the following code:

```
clientTableList = new Object[DBQueries.getAllClients().size()][3]; [I want to load 3 records for now]

LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> ClientHashMap = DBQueries.getAllClients();

System.out.println(clientHashMap.keySet());
//Printing all Values
System.out.println(clientHashMap.values());
```

Results:

```
[Bob Hope, Elena Hairr, Blossom Kraatz, Loreen Griepentrog]
[{UserID=2345, GivenName=Bob, FamilyName=Hope, DateOfBirth=August 30, 1963, NameSuffix=Sr, NamePrefix=, Email=francoise.rautenstrauch@rautenstrauch.com, Phone=519- ...
```

I need to load a `JTable`, my next code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clientHashMap.size(); i++) {
    clientTableList[i] = new Object[] {
        clientHashMap.get("GivenName") + " " + clientHashMap.get("FamilyName"),
        clientHashMap.get("LoginEmail") + " ",
        clientHashMap.get("Phone") + " " 
    };
```

But I'm getting all `null` for my `clientTableList`.

I need to load all values into a `HashTable` then load the `HashTable` into `clientTableList`. Right?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your `clientTableList` doesn't have those fields, only its values have them:

```
int i = 0;
for (Map<String, String> client: clientHashMap.values()) {
    clientTableList[i++] = String.format("%s %s %s %s",
            client.get("GivenName"),
            client.get("FamilyName"),
            client.get("LoginEmail"),
            client.get("Phone"));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Following changes worked:

```
clientTableList[i++] = new Object[]{ client.get("GivenName") + " " + client.get("FamilyName") , client.get("LoginEmail") + " " , client.get("Phone") + " " };
```